# Youtube Iframe Player messing up BottomNavBar positoning

Tags: flutter, dart, youtube-iframe-api, flutter-bottomnavigation

When I have the Youtube IFrame player be used on a page, once i navigate back to my previous page the bottom navbar (using speeddial package) is lowered. I don't know what might be causing this but i know its the Youtube player because i tested it by removing the YT player and the bottomNavBar was fine.

[Without Youtube Iframe Player Scaffold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Ob5.gif)

[With Youtube iFrame Player Scaffold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3wsF.gif)

Let me know what code you would like to see as its too large to place the three pages on this post atm.